# How do I replace single quotes with another character in sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a flat file where I have multiple occurrences of strings that contains single quote, e.g. `hari's` and `leader's`.

I want to replace all occurrences of the single quote with space, i.e.

- all occurences of `hari's` to `hari s`
- all occurences of `leader's` to `leader s`

I tried

```
sed -e 's/"'"/ /g' myfile.txt
```

and

```
sed -e 's/"'"/" "/g' myfile.txt
```

but they are not giving me the expected result.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try to keep sed commands simple as much as possible.
Otherwise you'll get confused of what you'd written reading it later.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed "s/'/ /g" myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 34):

This will do what you want to

```
echo "hari's"| sed 's/\x27/ /g'
```

It will replace single quotes present anywhere in your file/text. Even if they are used for quoting they will be replaced with spaces. In that case(remove the quotes within a word not at word boundary) you can use the following:

```
echo "hari's"| sed -re 's/(\<.+)\x27(.+\>)/\1 \2/g'
```

HTH

Answer (score 15):

Just go leave the single quote and put an escaped single quote:

```
sed 's/'\''/ /g' input
```

also possible with a variable:

```
quote=\'
sed "s/$quote/ /g" input
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is based on my own experience.

Please notice on how I use special char `'` vs `"` after `sed`

This won't do (no output)

```
2521 #> echo 1'2'3'4'5 | sed 's/'/ /g'
>
>
>
```

but This would do

```
2520 #> echo 1'2'3'4'5 | sed "s/'/ /g"
12345
```

Comment: I guess a bit of explanation would be nice. Also: Is this really a matter of Solaris or something else? (What else?)

Answer (score 0):

The -i should replace it in the file
   sed -i 's/“/"/g' filename.txt

if you want backups you can do
   sed -i.bak 's/“/"/g' filename.txt

Answer (score -1):

I had to replace "0x" string with "32'h" and resolved with:

```
sed 's/ 0x/ 32\x27h/'
```