# How to change a character with double quote mark

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am trying to replace the fancy quotation characters „ “ with normal " character. To do that I did the following but it did not change them. what should I do instead ?

```
sed -i 's/„/"/g' myfile.csv
```

Here is the SS of a single sentence from myfile.csv

[image]

EDIT:
Textual version of the SS placed above:

Glaubt man Union und FDP, dann wird ihre "Energiewende" mehr als nur ein Ausstieg – sie soll ein "Umstieg" werden.

Note: when I copy paste, the special character disappears. That is why I put screenshot at first.

Comment: And don't post screenshots of text files.

Comment: How are you examining the file? Can you please extract the relevant part, and if you're unable to copy-paste it as-is, can you base64 encode it? Double-check that it's correct by copying it back from your post and ensure that both show the same.

Comment: You could try dumping the file with `od -c` or something similar, and then using the codes in your `sed` program.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem, just tested this in bash and worked fine for replacing character `„`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace single quotes with another character in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17357952/608639), [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/608639), [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/608639), [sed command replace text with ' character](https://askubuntu.com/q/315344), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `tr` for example:

```
$ tr '„“' '"' < myfile.csv
```

You could try it like this:

```
$ echo "dann wird ihre „Energiewende“ mehr" | tr '„“' '"'
dann wird ihre "Energiewende" mehr
```

Comment: you shouldn't put the square brackets, with `tr` the char list is implied.  This will replace square brackets with double quotes as well.

Comment: @karakfa Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score -1):

You need to make two replacements, one for the opening quotes and one for the closing quotes. In other words:

```
sed -i 's/„/"/g;s/“/"/g' myfile.csv
```

or

```
sed -i 's/[„“]/"/g' myfile.csv
```

since you are replacing both with the same character.

Comment: Sure but I think my command should have replaced either of them. However it did not change.

Comment: @zwlayer You shouldn't berate somebody who tries to help you. Rather, you should create an example with your actual input - how are we supposed to know what exact character your input contains if you can't post an example containing it? Michael's commands are absolutely correct and will replace `„` and `“` with `"`. Maybe you have different smart quotes?